# cronjob gives 500 error

Tags: php, cron, server, internal

I run a cronjob on a php file
in the browser the php file does what it's supposed to do
when the file gets called as a cronjob I receive a 500 error

This happened after my host updated php (and cpanel I believe)
I suspect it's due to file permissions, but when I check file permissions, the file is 644 and directories to it; 755. So I don't see a problem there.

I turned email notifications on to troubleshoot this problem.
the email I received on the cronjob once:

```
cp: cannot create symbolic link `/var/fake/username/etc/./localtime': File exists
```

The error I keep finding in my log is:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1funn0quq65e0m6h1gt7i68eg4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: The error is self-explained. File exists and you attempt to overwrite it.

Comment: I can't even find /var/fake/username/etc/./localtime

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327126/what-is-a-dot-only-named-folder might help because I suspect it has to do with that part of the path

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going from PHP version 5.6 back to PHP 5.4
I still don't know what the real issue is.